# Can JAXB output an ArrayList as comma separated values?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I have something like

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="Mylist")
List<Items> myItems = new ArrayList<Items>()
```

and that comes  out like

```
<Mylist>
   <myItems>item 1</myItems>
   <myItems>item 2</myItems>
   <myItems>item 3</myItems>
</Mylist>
```

Is it possible to make this come out more like

```
<Mylist>
   <myItems>item 1, item 2, item 3</myItems>
</Mylist>
```

Since the data I am after is all just textual anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [@XmlList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlList.html) to make it a space separated value.

For a comma separated list you will need to use an [XmlAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html).  For more information on [XmlAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Comment: Are you saying in the new adapter class then I would simply cat all the items in the list together, and use @XmlValue on the newly created string?

Comment: Yes, then going the other direction you could tokenize the String on the ',' character.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `XmlAdapter` to handle comma separated lists:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class CommaSeparatedListAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, List<String>> {

    @Override
    public List<String> unmarshal(final String string) {
        final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (final String s : string.split(",")) {
            final String trimmed = s.trim();

            if (trimmed.length() > 0) {
                strings.add(trimmed);
            }
        }

        return strings;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(final List<String> strings) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (final String string : strings) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }

            sb.append(string);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="Mylist")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CommaSeparatedListAdapter.class)
List<Items> myItems = new ArrayList<Items>()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish that by making the field transient `@XmlTransient` and creating a method for calculating a String with a comma-separated.

```
@XmlTransient
List<Items> myItems = new ArrayList<Items>()

@XmlElement(name = "myItems")
public String getItemsAsCommasSeparated() {
    return String.join(", ", myItems);
}
```

About the wrapping `<Mylist>` if it is really necessary you will have to wrap the list into a another object.