# Marshalling a collection of String to one comma separated String

Tags: castor

I'm using Castor to marshal Java objects to and from XML as part of a Spring WS web service.

One of the object's properties is a Collection of String and instead of listing each item as a separate element, I want to marshal it into a single element value as a comma separated string.

Could someone suggest how I might do this? Couldn't figure out a mapping and am struggling with creating an appropriate FieldHandler, without rewriting GeneralizedFieldHandler...

Doesn't feel like this should be very difficult, but I've been pulling my hair out.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how tied to Castor you are, but you could use an XMLAdapter to do this in JAXB:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936811/can-jaxb-output-an-arraylist-as-comma-separated-values/3936856#3936856